# XPath get value of attribute 'A' based on attribute 'B' in SQL Server xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath

I have this XML in SQL Server

```
<data>
<add key="images" value="image/path/img.gif" />
<data>
```

I want to select the value attribute of every "add" node with key = "images"

What i have now is:

```
SELECT ID, Data from Items 
where Data.value('(//data/add[@key="images"]/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar') Like '%img%'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have works fine if you just specify a size for your `nvarchar` retrieved from the XML.

```
SELECT ID, Data
from Items 
where Data.value('(//data/add[@key="images"]/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Like '%img%'
```

Here I have specified `100` you may set it to something more appropriate for your situation. Without the size the column will have size `1`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
(//data
    /add
      [@key="images"]
         /@value
            [contains(.,"img")]
 )
 [1]
```